# Do you need Schengen travel insurance if you have a private health insurance from a Schengen country as a resident of that country?

Tags: schengen, insurance

While traveling in Schengen, do you need Schengen travel insurance if you have a private health insurance from a Schengen country as a resident of that country?

Asking this question to learn the usual recommendation or usual practice

Comment: Does your private insurance cover medical expenses in the country you are intending to travel to?

Comment: Does your private health insurance bring you home? Depending on your condition you might need a lot of space on the plane and maybe a nurse.

Comment: I don't know yet. I posted this question to learn the usual recommendation or usual practice

Comment: As insurance rules differ so much, there might well not be a usual recommendation or practice. (I used to take out insurance with bring home covering but without the usual medical part, as that was covered by the home medical insurance. Others may or may not have different coverage.)

Comment: The Visa code (Article 15) states: *valid **travel medical insurance** to cover any expenses which might arise in connection with repatriation for medical reasons, urgent medical attention and/or emergency hospital treatment or death, during their stay(s) on the territory of the Member States.* ... *The minimum coverage shall be €30000.*. Either your private private health insurance can cover this **or** you have the means to pay this yourself.

Comment: @MarkJohnson And you think the visa code applies why?

Comment: @Relaxed I don't and didn't say it did. But the OP is asking: 'usual recommendation or usual practice' and the visa code can serve as a guideline for that.

Comment: You may want to specify your country of residence and the nature of your insurance. There are country where “private insurance” means a specific type of insurance that is outside the scope of the European Health Insurance Card system (e.g. Germany) but there are also countries where statutory health insurance is managed by private businesses (the Netherlands).

Comment: @MarkJohnson Not really but either way, if you don't think it does apply, you should have stated that right away because your comment was very misleading.

Comment: @Relaxed The last sentances is clear enough for most peaple.

Comment: @MarkJohnson The last sentence is very clear indeed, it's the most misleading one. It implies there are only two terms to this alternative, as in you *require* one or the other. In actual fact, the whole thing doesn't apply (a very cogent fact you completely omitted) and people might have very different views on what's an acceptable level of risk or coverage.

Comment: @Relaxed Well, that is your opinion. If it is good enough for someone who requires a visa, it will be good enough for someone who doesn't.

Comment: @MarkJohnson My opinion is merely that this is not a *fact*, there is no hard alternative here but the usual trade-offs with insurance with a myriad of other positions that can be reasonable (what about €50k? €80k? Counting on your parents to pay? etc.) You're now trying to disguise your original mistake as a kind of (rather unconvincing) advice on what's “good enough” as health care insurance but that's not what your original comment stated and the notion that the visa code provides an objective yardstick for that is obviously nonsense.

Comment: @Relaxed Again, that is your opinion. Where *minimum coverage* is given it is clear that it can be more. This is something that many ask their health provider about. Knowing what the minimum is helps to understand what they are offering (Something you didn't meantion in you answer). So please stop your consistent hysteria.

Comment: @MarkJohnson So you admit it's completely useless as advice on insurance matters and really just define a minimum legal requirement… that doesn't apply here?

Comment: @Relaxed Please learn how to read.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I am ready to read your answer, do you agree or not? Sometimes it seems you, sometimes you try to be evasive about it…

Comment: Make sure you look into acquiring a European Health Insurance Card (EHIC) to which you are likely entitled and will provide most healthcare in all EU/EEA countries - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Health_Insurance_Card

Comment: @JackAidley thanks for the tip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> While traveling in Schengen, do you need Schengen travel insurance if you have a private health insurance from a Schengen country as a resident of that country?

You don't specifically need *Schengen* travel insurance. What is usually called Schengen travel insurance is the insurance required under article 15 of regulation 810/2009 (Schengen Visa Code) and it does not apply to you as a resident – or to visa-exempt visitors – but only to people who require a short-stay Schengen visa (which you do not). There is no comparable requirement in the Schengen Borders Code.

Beyond that, you may want to check what your current health insurance covers or if you have some other coverage, e.g. through a credit card or travel insurance of some sort. This may or may not include paying for regular care for chronic illnesses you still require while traveling, primary or emergency care if you have an unexpected accident or health issue abroad, and medical transport back to your country of residence after an accident. Specifically traveling for medical treatment is typically outside the scope of these types of insurance as are search and rescue costs and outdoors activities but there really isn't any rule here, you have to figure out what you already have and decide what you feel comfortable with.

If you do feel you need extra coverage, you are more likely to be well served by some local travel or travel health insurance than a “Schengen travel insurance”, which is really designed to cover the legal requirement and doesn't offer extensive coverage or especially good value. If you go down that route, do check in the fine print that coverage doesn't depend on you being affiliated to the local statutory health insurance system.